# Recovering log in information

Tags: login

we are running two websites on WP. We had an external person managing both of them but unfortunately he passed away recently. We had the password and username for one of them but for the other website we never got the info to log on etc. It is a fairly new website and he didn't get the time to give us the info before he passed. Was wondering if theres anyway of recovering the account or the log in details?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Alex

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the database you can modify the the password using MD5 on edit.... Here is a resource that will describe what I'm saying.

You will need to scroll down to see how to do this is PhpMyAdmin.  Other than using the Lost Password link this is the only way I know of if there is no other Admin user...

https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-reset-a-wordpress-password-from-phpmyadmin/##targetText=Why%20Reset%20WordPress%20Password%20from%20phpMyAdmin&targetText=You%20can%20simply%20go%20to,address%20to%20reset%20the%20password.